# mysqlnt.exe uses 50% of CPU

Tags: mysql

While executing SQL Scripts, mysqlnt.exe uses 50% of CPU . Even there is no access, the CPU usage doesn't come down. Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have a dual core machine, and some MySQL session is using 100% of one of your cores/processors.

Open the MySQL command line client, and issue a

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

to see what sessions are currently running, what they are doing, and how long they are doing it. If you get a feeling who de culprit is, and you can safely abort it, Issue a

```
KILL ###
```

Where ### is the number of a session (found in the Id column of the SHOW PROCESSLIST output)

Comment: I've killed the unused threads. There is only 4 live connections right now. But still the the process eats 50% of the box ? Is there anything I need to change in the "Start up variables" section ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to diagnose what query is causing the problem, you should probably optimize it and add some indexes on questioned table.

Use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` for getting list of processes and then run it with `EXPLAIN` to see why it takes so long.

Answer (score 0):

try to make indexing on your table - also you need to make some performance - tunning on your query - so which makes it much faster :-) optimize it - I'm agree with Michal Chihar !